# Dividing row by row beneath it in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so :

```
block partner prSwitch
1   p1  0.06666667
1   p2  0.06666667
2   p1  0.03333333
2   p2  0.06666667
3   p1  0.10000000
3   p2  0.06666667
4   p1  0.06666667
4   p2  0.03333333
5   p1  0.10000000
5   p2  0.13333333
6   p1  0.06666667
6   p2  0.23333333
```

I would like to divide each row with p1 with the one with p2 in the same block and that for every block.

I'd like my new df to look like this :

```
block  prSwitch of p1/p2
1   0.06666667
2   0.03333333
3   0.10000000
4   0.06666667
5   0.10000000
6   0.06666667
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(block) %>%
  summarize(prSwitch_p1_p2_ratio = prSwitch[partner == "p1"] / prSwitch[partner == "p2"])
```

This will throw an error if you don't have a single `p1` and `p2` within a block.

Answer (score 0):

In Base R we could use this

```
new_df <- data.frame(
    block = unique(df$block),
    "prSwitch of p1/p2" = sapply(split(df, df$block), function(x) x$prSwitch[1] / x$prSwitch[2]) 
)

> new_df
  block prSwitch.of.p1.p2
1     1         1.0000000
2     2         0.4999999
3     3         1.4999999
4     4         2.0000003
5     5         0.7500000
6     6         0.2857143
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape your data to wide format. This will also work nicely if either a p1 or p2 value is missing.

```
DF <- read.table(text = "block partner prSwitch
1   p1  0.06666667
1   p2  0.06666667
2   p1  0.03333333
2   p2  0.06666667
3   p1  0.10000000
3   p2  0.06666667
4   p1  0.06666667
4   p2  0.03333333
5   p1  0.10000000
5   p2  0.13333333
6   p1  0.06666667
6   p2  0.23333333", header = TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF1 <- dcast(DF, block ~ partner)
DF1$quotient <- DF1$p1 / DF1$p2
#  block         p1         p2  quotient
#1     1 0.06666667 0.06666667 1.0000000
#2     2 0.03333333 0.06666667 0.4999999
#3     3 0.10000000 0.06666667 1.4999999
#4     4 0.06666667 0.03333333 2.0000003
#5     5 0.10000000 0.13333333 0.7500000
#6     6 0.06666667 0.23333333 0.2857143
```